# align right values inside popup created by ion-select, when dir is rtl, part of the value isn't shown

Tags: ionic3

When i set `dir` to `rtl`, the elements of ion-select in the popup messages aligned right but part of it is hidden.
[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: the radio button icons in this select, when the direction is ltr, they are shown correctly without being padded and hidden inside the edges of the container, but when dir is rtl, it's like in the photo, padded outside the edges of the container